# upload file async to method of ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method of ApiController (server) to upload files:

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{    
    public Task<IEnumerable<FileDesc>> Post()
    {
        string folderName = "UploadFiles";
        string PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName);
        string rootUrl = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, String.Empty);


        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(PATH);

            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileDesc>>(t =>
            {

                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }

                var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
                {
                    var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                    return new FileDesc(info.Name, PATH + "/" + info.Name, info.Length / 1024);
                });
                return fileInfo;
            });

            return task;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }

    }
```

and the following code to call this method (client):

```
    private void UploadFiles(string file)
    {
        ThreadSafeUpdateStatus(Properties.Resources.Sending1);
        ProgressMessageHandler progress = new ProgressMessageHandler();
        progress.HttpSendProgress += new EventHandler<HttpProgressEventArgs>(HttpSendProgress);

        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
        {
            Error("Upload files", "File '" + file + "' not found", "Screenshot was not published. Please, try again.", true);
        }
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);

        content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", _filename);

        message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        message.Content = content;
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(((App)Application.Current).HostRESTful);

        try
        {
            var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progress);
            sending = client.SendAsync(message);
            CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

            string error = Properties.Resources._SendingFailedUnknownError;
            sending.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                try
                {
                    bool resultUpload = ServiceTools.HttpResult(task, "SendingWindow/UploadFiles : upload file to server"); // если false - Окно с линками всё-равно открыто!!!!

                    if (resultUpload)
                    {
                        var ver = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
                        string lang = String.Empty;
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
                        {
                            lang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
                        });

                        var clientDescr = new HttpClient();

                        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("filename", _filename));
                        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("clientDateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.dd.MM HH:mm")));
                        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("title", _title));
                        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("description", _description));
                        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("isPublic", _isPublic.ToString()));
                        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("version", ver.Major.ToString() + "." + ver.Minor.ToString() + "." + ver.Build.ToString()));
                        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("lang", lang));

                        HttpContent contentDescr = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

                        clientDescr.PutAsync(((App)Application.Current).HostRESTful, contentDescr).ContinueWith(

                        ThreadSafeUpdateStatus(Properties.Resources._SendingSuccess);
                        ShellFolder.UpdateElementScreenshotsXmlAsSent(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));

                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
                        {
                            Close();
                        });


                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    error = Properties.Resources._RemoteServerNotAvailable;

                    TryToSendAgain(error);
                }
            }, token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ServiceTools.WriteToWebService("SendingWindow/UploadFiles: publishing", ex);
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown error during publishing");

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
            {
                Close();
                //FadeClosing();
            });
        }
    }
```

it works fine, but only when PC has .NET 4.5 installed!!! If PC does not have it - I get "Unknown error during publishing" error and exception

> Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler'
>   from assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I spent 2 days to fix it - no result. Solution can be compiled, but could not load type! I need start my application on PCs with .NET 4.0 (and without .NET 4.5) therefore I solved to rewrite client part to use HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse (or WebClient). But I really don't understand how to call "ht_tp://my...domain/api/upload" correctly using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse. Or I even agree to rewrite server part too, but don't know how to do it with progress.
Or I would be happy, if someone show me how to solve this stupid problem with .NET 4.5 requirements. I have read all posts on stackoverflow about this - no help me...

Comment: If you are using Web API 2 (assembly version 5.0), then .NET 4.5 is required for it. Web API 1 should work fine with .NET 4.0.

Comment: I use Web API 1, assembly is compiled fine (even on PC without .NET 4.5), but get an exception in runtime